# calling C++ functions via GDB

Tags: c++, templates, gdb, method-call

I have been using GDBs "call" functionality for last few weeks and it seems very useful
Code like below

```
 void VectorPrint(const std::vector<int>& v)
    {
      std::cout << "start printing vector\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) { 
            std::cout << v[i]; 
            if (i != v.size() - 1) 
                std::cout << "\n"; 
        } 
        //std::cout << "\n printing end \n";
    }
```

**(gdb) call VectorPrint(any1DVectorhere)**
*This executes the above function and prints the vector contents on console.*

***The issue I am facing is, I am unable to call the same function if it is templated, something like below. GDB does not recognize the templated functions***

```
template <typename Traits>
    template <typename myVec>
    void MyClass<Traits>::VectorPrint(const std::vector<myVec>& v)
    {
      std::cout << "start printing vector\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) { 
            std::cout << v[i]; 
            if (i != v.size() - 1) 
                std::cout << "\n"; 
        } 
        //std::cout << "\n printing end \n";
    }
```

Could anyone suggest how to get the **call** functionality working with GDB in this usecase ?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: gdb or any debugger can call only the methods that already exist. If template instantiation has never occurred in your code for a particular type, then that call cannot happen. Make sure there exists such instantiation and show how you call the function in gdb.

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that you have to use the template at least once in your code for **that specific instantiation** of the template to be created by the compiler. Second, even if you do that, the name won't be just `VectorPrint`. It will be something similar to `VectorPrint<type>`. Try pressing TAB after writing `call VectorPr` to see the available instances that gdb is seeing.

I have written a longer explanation about this [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61674147/printing-blitz-arrays-via-gdb/61685917#61685917).